# Warning INI parameter missing in Z3 3.2?

Tags: configuration, parameters, warnings, ini, z3

According to the list of [INI parameters](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/config.html) there should be a boolean WARNING flag, but setting it in Z3 3.2 (x64_mt) via

```
(set-option :WARNING false)
```

yields `unsupported` for both spellings `WARNING` and `warning`.

Are the docs outdated or I am doing something wrong here?

**[EDIT]**

According to the [release notes of Z3 2.17](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/releasenotes.html#sec_release_z3_2_17) the option should be set via

```
(set-option WARNING <flag>)
```

but trying

```
(set-option WARNING false)
```

yields

```
(error "line 1 column 13: invalid command argument, keyword expected")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, seems as if the docs are outdated. I finally found

```
(set-option :print-warning false)
```

in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8185080/491216) and it works.